# How to convert Castle Windsor fluent config to xml

Tags: castle-windsor

I would like to convert this fluent approach to xml:

```
container.Register(
    AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("Company.DataAccess")
        .BasedOn(typeof(IReadDao<>)).WithService.FromInterface(),
    AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("Framework.DataAccess.NHibernateProvider")
        .BasedOn(typeof(IReadDao<>)).WithService.Base());
```

Is there any way of doing this, maintaining the simplicity?

Comment: Jonathas, this is a Q&A site, not a regular forum. You completely changed the question, thus invalidating the existing answers. Please revert your changes and create a new question instead.

Comment: Done! I created a new question: <a href='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638243/how-can-i-configure-a-factory-with-the-possible-providers'>How can I configure a Factory with the possible providers?</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to do batch registrations in XML. If you really want to express this in XML (I wonder why) you'll have to enumerate each component to be registered.

The closest thing was the [batch registration facility](http://www.castleproject.org/container/facilities/trunk/batch/index.html), but it has been deprecated.

Comment: You convinced me. I will try other approach. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try Binsor, which is a Boo DSL for registering components, but I'm not entirely sure how up to date it is.

Be advised that what you're trying to do is not a recommended practice and brings more headaches than true value. Stick to code.